# Libnodave on value changed

Tags: plc, libnodave

I am using libnodave 0.8.4.4 library to connect to a S7 PLC and what I would like to know if how can I detect if a bit (e.g. DB100.DBX8.0) in PLC DB changes its value. What I did is to read this bit within a while loop but I would like to create an event on value changed on this bit and launch a task when it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default event available with `libnodave` or any other libraries like `S7.net`.

Either you need to use `OPC`or write your own function which will read the set of bits set on time and notify to the main program.

Comment: I use libnodave with Delphi and in my app I need to know if a bit is on in order to read the PLC data. I've used a timer for this task. Every second (I nedd to test the bit every second) it fire a funcion that read the bit I need and if it is on I read the data from the PLC.